# Rails 3- What is the alternative solution of CSV.parse_line in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, csv

In rails 2, I used CSV.parse_line to read csv files.
In Rails 3, CSV.parse_line is not present. I used line.split but it is not working when there is comma (,) present in one word. It split it into two columns.

I want to know that is there is any alternative solution of CSV.parse_line in Rails 3?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternative CVS lib, named [smartcsv](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv)
It provides good documentation and more options than the default CVS parser implemetation you can find on standard Ruby.